# parsing ethtool command output using sed and awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I am working on a shell script to parse the advertised mode and supported mode from the `ethtool` command and match them against an expected value. The idea is both expected and supported modes should have a common value to pass the condition.

Data:

```
# ethtool eth5                                                                                                                                                                          
Settings for eth1:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        Supported ports: [ Backplane ]                                                                                                                                                                                   
        Supported link modes:   1000baseKX/Full                                                                                                                                                                          
                                10000baseKR/Full                                                                                                                                                                         
                                15000baseKR/Full                                                                                                                                                                         
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric                                                                                                                                                                             
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes                                                                                                                                                                                   
        Supported FEC modes: None BaseR RS                                                                                                                                                                               
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseKX/Full                                                                                                                                                                          
                                10000baseKR/Full                                                                                                                                                                         
                                15000baseKR/Full
```

I have currently used the below for the same.

```
link_mode_expected=15000baseKR

# get the mode using the shell command and parse the value needed
mode_supported=`ethtool ${eth_device} | sed -ne '/Supported link modes:/,/:/p' |\
sed  -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'  -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' | grep "$link_mode_expected"`
mode_advertised=`ethtool ${eth_device} | sed -ne '/Advertised link modes:/,/:/p' |\
sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'  -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' | grep "$link_mode_expected"`

if [ "$mode_supported" != "$link_mode_expected" ] ||\
    ( [ "$mode_supported" != "$mode_advertised" ] ) ; then
        
     #some action
fi
```

The above code is giving the correct result that is 15000baseKR/Full for both `mode_advertised` and `mode_supported` and I am doing the logic as above but I am looking for help with below

1. how to avoid two `ethtool` commands, can we add the output to a buffer and grep from that buffer?
2. what is the awk equivalent of the same and if awk is faster in execution?
3. Is there any better approach than the above?

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the expected output that currently I am getting and input data.

Comment: As an aside, modern command substitution syntax uses `$(ethtool | ...)` rather than backticks. Perhaps see also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) - you could easily add a condition to your `sed` script to only print lines with the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk will indeed be the answer to all your questions here.

```
link_mode_expected=15000

if ethtool "$eth_device" |
   awk -v lme="$link_mode_expected" '
      s && /:/ { s=0 }
      /Supported link modes:/ { s=1 }
      s && ($NF + 0 == lme) { sgood++ }
      a && /:/ { a=0 }
      /Advertised link modes:/ { a=1 }
      a && ($NF + 0 == lme) { agood++ }
      END { exit 1-(agood && sgood) }'
then
    # some action
fi
```

Demo, with some debug prints: https://ideone.com/v5du8g

Having Awk perform the comparison and set its exit status for `if` to examine is slightly clunky on the Awk side, but makes the script very easy and natural to use from the surrounding shell script.

Like `sed`, Awk processes one line (or, more specifically, one record) per iteration. In this script, the simple variables `s` and `a` reflect whether the current input line is inside a region which enumerates the supported or advertised modes, respectively. If we are in such a region, we check if the last field on the line (`$NF`) evaluates numerically (`+ 0`) to the number in `lme`. Awk conveniently ignores any nonnumeric tail on the value in this scenario. At the end, we set the exit status to 0 for success (both the values were found) or 1 otherwise, in accordance with the shell's conventions (zero exit code means success, anything else is a failure).

As an alternative approach, you could try to figure out a record separator (`RS`) to split on, instead of newline. Splitting on a colon might be good, as then you can examine the entire region in one go (but then you lose the simple and elegant feature that `NF` contains the index of the field you want to examine, so it might not be simpler at all in the end).

You could also opt to simply have Awk extract and print the values, and then do the comparison in the shell; but having the shell parse the output from Awk which you just spent so much time parsing is stilted and unattractive.

This script isn't entirely trivial, but you should find that learning enough Awk to write simpler scripts is quite pleasant and quick, and very well worth your time. You can get pretty far already on a budget of 30 minutes to an hour.

Ad-hoc output formats which require custom parsers are a constant source of frustration and friction. Increasingly, modern tools have options to produce output in properly machine-readable standard formats like JSON, YAML, or XML. Alas, `ethtool` unfortunately does not seem to have any such facility.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, Can you explain a bit on the what you are doing here ? "s && /:/ { s=0 }  /Supported link modes:/ { s=1 }"  and what region the above code points to ? I believe it's till next: in the output?  
Also, how can we compare 15000baseKR instead of only numeric, as there might be modes with 15000base vs 15000baseKR and we need to select only if the second is available?

Comment: `s` is true if we previously saw the header for supported modes. If it's true and we see another `:`, we are now out of that region. The following condition is the one which allows us to enter the region. They confusingly have to be in this order to avoid exiting the region as soon as we entered (because the entry condition string also contains a colon).

Comment: It's not hard to examine the string after the number but it's not clear from your comment what the logic should be. Perhaps ignore the value if it doesn't contain "baseKR"? `s && /baseKR/ && ($NF + 0 == lme)`?

Comment: I'll repeat my recommendation to spend half an hour on a basic Awk tutorial. Then maybe ask a separate question with a link back here if you need more help. The [`awk` tag info page on Stack Overflow](/tags/awk/info) has an overview and a collection of links.

Comment: Thanks again, sure will check on the awk. Yeah the point is I have to check a particular mode that combines speed + other things, like 15000baseKR, as there are other modes with the same speed like 15000baseSR, 15000basePR etc,

Comment: Sorry, I had somehow overlooked the text part of `link_mode_expected`. You could avoid the arithmetic tricks and just check whether `$NF` starts with the label followed by a slash delimiter `s && ($NF ~ "^" label "/")` where `label="15000baseKR"`